# Validate a registration form using ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

Can anyone give me some simple code to validate a registration form using ajax?

Comment: You probably only really need straight Javascript for any kind of form validation. The AJAX component would be if you were pulling something back from the server for this - not necessary in most cases, unless you're doing fairly advanced stuff. I'd revise your question accordingly.

Comment: Also, you have 10 questions asked, with zero accepted answers. People are going to stop answering your questions if you don't go through and accept some answers on old questions (by clicking the checkmark to the left of the text)

Comment: pick up a book. gotta learn to crawl before you walk.

Comment: Accept an answer from the list below or cancel the question? Is there a reason you don't accept answers?

Comment: Looking for something similar myself, hopefully ur answers can help me too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this with google - http://jqueryfordesigners.com/using-ajax-to-validate-forms/

Seems to be a good one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing something like a username, to see whether it exists (I assume this would be the reason for javascript) - Just format your response in a specific way ie

If username/email is ok: "OK", if not "FAIL" - then (my code is jQuery based because it's alot easier to write than straight javascript)

```
 $("input[name='emailAddress']").onblur(function() {
      $.ajax({
           url:"/checkemailaddress?email="+$(this).val(),
           success: function(response) {
                if(response=="OK"){
                     $(this).removeClass("RedCross").addClass("GreenTick");
                } else {
                     $(this).removeClass("GreenTick").addClass("RedCross");
                }

           }

      });

 });
```

Codes not tested by the way!

Answer (score 0):

### Very short answer.

Use the the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation).

### Short answer

I advise you to use a framework. jQuery is an excellent one, and the jQuery AJAX API works like a charm. Your specific problem can be solved with the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation).

### Long answer

Most people don't write pure JavaScript (and thus AJAX) anymore, but start with a framework. Frameworks have a lot of benefits.

For example, you don't have to worry about the differences in javascript between different browsers: the framework (mostly) does this for you.

One example of a popular framework these days is jQuery. If you learn to work with jQuery, writing JavaScript code will be a lot easier, faster and your code will contain less bugs.

A lot of code already exists. **To work with AJAX, jQuery offers the excellent [AJAX API](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)**. There are tutorials all around the web, and if you encounter specific problems with AJAX examples or your jQuery code, StackOverflow is filled with jQuery experts, so post them here.

Offcourse you are not the first person who wants to validate form input using AJAX. The problem is so often encountered that some kind soul published the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation). This plugin allows you to easily validate your form input, and you can extend it with your own functionality should you need to.